# tomcat on ubuntu jnetpcap native library *.so unable to load

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, jnetpcap

I want to deploy my application on to tomcat which has a pcap parsing ability. The module was running fine on eclipse / terminal. On tomcat i see the error as below.

[image: pic]

I have tried the following steps to resolve this issue:

1. Add jnetpcap.jar and *.so (2 files for 1.4r1425 version) into $PATH
2. Add jnetpcap.jar in tomcat lib folder
3. In JAVA i tried using `System.loadLibrary("path/to/so/files");`

None of them worked. Also how does tomcat load native libraries is something i have no knowledge about. Kindly suggest a solution to make this work on tomcat.

Comment: make sure you using right library architecture, x86 or x86_64

Comment: can you please be more descriptive

Comment: there are libraries for jnetpcap x86 and x86_64, if your system is x64 you need x86_64 libraries, if 32 bit, you need x86 libraries.

Comment: The linked question explains what you need to do to get Tomcat to recognize a native library or DLL.

Comment: Stephen can you please point me to the correct location if this is already answered. I have already referred to many links here. Its working on terminal so i assume i am using the correct libraries. My ubuntu is 64-bit and am using http://slytechs.com/downloads/dist/a130819os/jnetpcap-1.4.r1425-1.linux64.x86_64.tgz